# Proving an estimate for a function that is null on the boundary of the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $B_1(0)$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f \in C^1(\overline{B_1(0)})$ such that $f$ is identically zero on $\partial B_1(0)$. Prove that $$|f(0)| \leq\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{B_1(0)}|\nabla f(x)||x|^{-2}dx$$
I have absolutely no idea of how to do this! Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking to [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem)... but don't see how to apply it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good start: Let $S$ denote the unit sphere. For any $y\in S,$ we have

$$-f(0)=f(y)-f(0)= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dr}f(ry)\,dr = \int_0^1 \nabla f(ry)\cdot y\,dr.$$

It follows that

$$-f(0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_S \int_0^1 \nabla f(ry)\cdot y\,dr \,ds(y).$$

Here $ds$ is surface measure on $S.$ Now take your integral $\dfrac{1}{4\pi}\int_{B_1(0)}|\nabla f(x)||x|^{-2}dx,$ integrate in spherical coordinates, and use the above.